# How can i add Programming code to HTML page?

Tags: html

I want to add a code area to my html page. The area should seem like in the studios. For example **JAVA** codes should seem like how it seems in eclipse.

Is there a template or anything like it? 
By the way it doesn't have to seem fully like in studios, just a simple code area.

Comment: Do you know the HTML tags `<code>` and `<pre>`?

Comment: no i dont, i've never seen it

Comment: Learn it, it's the starting point of your journey: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want do it with pure html you can use the tags `<pre>` and `<code>` but you should add some css to set the look and feel you want.

```
<pre>
  <code>
    public void main(){
     ...
    }
  </code>
</pre>
```

I recommend to you use a javascript text editor called **code mirror** (http://codemirror.net/). It's a great tool, easy to use and it supports multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **GeSHi** - Generic Syntax Highlighter. 
If you're using WordPress, the [WP-Syntax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-syntax/) plugin is cool.

Comment: Thank you this is one of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend **highlightjs**. https://highlightjs.org/usage/

If you want to style it like eclipse, you can also apply some prebuilt themes. https://highlightjs.org/static/test.html